# Strict Standards: Non-static method (joomla and roksprocket)

Tags: php, joomla, strict

`Strict Standards: Non-static method K2ModelItemlist::getCategoryTree() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\virgin\components\com_roksprocket\lib\RokSprocket\Provider\K2\Filter.php on line 151`

All

I have this error...I am using RokSprocket, Joomla and received the above error... It seems to have originated from

```php
protected function category($data)
{
if(file_exists(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_k2/models/itemlist.php'))
require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_k2/models/itemlist.php');
$wheres = array();
foreach($data as $match){
$categories = K2ModelItemlist::getCategoryTree($match);
```

Any idea how to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by add link to theme? The site is still on my localserver

Comment: Did you downloaded it?

Comment: I am not clean on what you are asking.. Can you clarify... Rocksprocket module is http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/roksprocket  and Joomla CMS is http://www.joomla.org/

Comment: If you have question about source code try to link on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making Joomla compatible with the strict requirements are still work in progress. The core has come a long way on that road, but many extension developers are still not aware of current best practices.

### Development Environment

Stay with the maximum `error_level`, just repair the broken code by prepending the `function` keyword with `public static`. You'll loose that on updates, but your VCS will help you to re-fix that quickly.

### Production Environment

On productive systems, `error_reporting` can be lowered to not include strict warnings. Configure the server to log errors instead of displaying them.

Comment: Here is how you can contribute to Joomla!: http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla/contribute-to-joomla.html

Answer (score 0):

`K2ModelItemlist::getCategoryTree` not defined as static. There for you got that error message.

Yes, you can define it as static yourself inside file `components/com_k2/models/itemlist.php`

```
function getCategoryTree($categories) // line 576
```

replace with

```
static function getCategoryTree($categories)
```

But you must remember every your own patch of foreign components cause you can lose it after upgrading.

Comment: I suggest you fill in bug report/ issue so the fixes are merged into official distribution of extension: [getk2: Issues](https://code.google.com/p/getk2/issues/list). You'll help others with same problem and don't have to worry about losing changes after upgrades.

Comment: @piotr_cz, it's not issue of k2, they use it right. It's issue of RokSprocket and they [already know about it](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=611&t=195649&p=959880&hilit=getCategoryTree&rb_v=viewtopic#p959880).

Comment: Probably you are right. Solution would then be to get model instance `$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('ItemList', 'K2Model', array('ignore_request' => true));` and access it's method: `$categories = $model->getCategoryTree($match);` Moreover require_once should be replaced with `JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_k2/models', 'K2Model');`