# S5 Register Module error

Tags: joomla

I'm using J25 and S5 module register. When I click Register button  and register an account I'll get this error:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/s10s/public_html/modules/mod_s5_register/captcha/validate.php on line 21
```

I got it whenever I try to register new account. I tried to disable the Captcha setting in Module **mod_s5_register** and Users Configuration but it didn't work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla throws quite a few strict standards errors.  More on that in the chosen answer here...

[Strict Standards: Non-static method (joomla and roksprocket)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533288/strict-standards-non-static-method-joomla-and-roksprocket)

In your case, there's probably just a stray ampersand on that line.  However, warnings are just warnings so turning off strict errors on the server should be enough for the site to display correctly.  I assume it is working, just throwing that warning?